# Batch file to copy part of command line

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way for me to make a batch file that will copy part of the command line? For example, this is the command line that pops up when I run:

```
wmic process where name="XXXX" get Commandline
```

The result is:

```
"C:/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX" "XXXX" "XXXX" "XXXX" "AAAAAA AAAA XX"
```

I just want to copy the AAAAAA AAAA part of the command line. All the things before it is fixed in size.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You put in a for loop

```
for /f "tokens=5,6 delims= " %A in ('wmic process where "name='cmd.exe'" get Commandline') do echo %A %B
```